# vhdl function package test

Tags: function, vhdl

I've recently begun to use functions in VHDL and I'm trying to call a package of functions I created in one of my VHDL entities.
First, here's the code of the entity that calls the functions to affect a 3 bits bus entry.

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use work.Func_Pack.ALL;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Math_Function is

Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Game_Mode : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Random_Number : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
       Modified_Number : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0));
end Math_Function;

architecture Behavioral of Math_Function is

BEGIN

Out_Circuit : PROCESS (clk)

BEGIN

    IF rising_edge(clk) THEN

        IF Game_Mode = '1' THEN
            IF rand = ("001" or "010") THEN
                Modified_Number <= function1;
            ELSIF rand = ("011" or "100") THEN
                Modified_Number <= function2;
            ELSIF rand = ("101" or "110") THEN
                Modified_Number <= function3;
            ELSE
                Modified_Number <= Random_Number;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            Modified_Number <= Random_Number;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS Out_Circuit;
end Behavioral;
```

And the code of the function package that is supposed to modify the entry bus called `Random_Number` with some simple arithmetic operations.

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;


package Func_Pack is

function rand(Random_Number : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector;

function function1(Random_Number : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector;

function function2(Random_Number : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector;

function function3(Random_Number : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) return 
std_logic_vector;


end package;

package body Func_Pack is


function rand(Random_Number : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector is
variable number : integer range 0 to 9 ;
variable out_number : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) ;

begin

number := 0;
number := to_integer(unsigned(Random_Number)) ;
out_number := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(number / 2, 4)) ;
return out_number ;

end rand;

function function1(Random_Number : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) 

return

std_logic_vector is
variable number : integer range 0 to 9 ;
variable out_number : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) ;

begin

number := 0;

number := to_integer(unsigned(Random_Number)) ;

out_number := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(number mod 2 + 6, 4)) ;

return out_number ; 

end function1;

function function2(Random_Number : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) 
return std_logic_vector is

variable number : integer range 0 to 9 ;

variable out_number : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) ;

begin

number := 0;

number := to_integer(unsigned(Random_Number)) ;

out_number := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(number + 3, 4)) ;

return out_number ;

end function2;

function function3(Random_Number : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) 
return 
std_logic_vector is

variable number : integer range 0 to 9 ;

variable out_number : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) ;

begin

number := 0;

number := to_integer(unsigned(Random_Number)) ;

out_number := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(number - number mod 2 + 2, 4));

return out_number ;

end function3;

end package body;
```

As I previously said, I'm new to packages and functions and there might still be syntax errors or mistakes in my code.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of question. Depending of the result of the function rand on the Random_Number input, the behavioral is supposed to perform function 1, 2 and 3, which modify the value of Random_Number with arithmetic operations and then return it and affect it to the output Modified_Number. So I guess the question would be: Am I using the functions right or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of explicit question notwithstanding, I assume you're having problems with:

```
IF rand = ("001" or "010") THEN
  Modified_Number <= function1;
ELSIF rand = ("011" or "100") THEN
  Modified_Number <= function2;
ELSIF rand = ("101" or "110") THEN
  Modified_Number <= function3;
ELSE
  Modified_Number <= Random_Number;
END IF;
```

You've written `function1`, for instance, so that it takes an argument, but you're not providing one. The function prototype is:

```
function function1(Random_Number : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector;
```

You need to provide the required argument when you call the function, like:

```
IF rand = ("001" or "010") THEN
  Modified_Number <= function1(rand);
```

Also be careful, as you appear to have several potential off-by-one errors - for one, your output `Modified_Number` is a 5-bit vector, but you assign the result of your functions, which return `out_number`, which is only 4 bits.

**(edit)**

Above, I missed the fact that `rand` was itself a function that takes an argument. Your if statement should then be `if rand(Random_Number) = ...` (see Brian's answer for another problem with the rest of those lines as you had them written).

Just make sure you understand the scope of the names you're using in your function. You wrote each function to take an argument `Random_Number`. This is *not* the same as your `Random_Number` input port to your `Math_Function` entity - they happen to have the same name, but they're in different scopes, and the function does not automatically use the input port as its argument. From the perspective of the function, the name of the argument (the LRM term is "formal parameter") is a name local to that function only. When you declare a port, also named `Random_Number`, you need to explicitly pass it to each function call.

Note that you could also just declare your functions in your architecture body, in which case signals outside the function itself *would* be in scope, provided you declared it as impure (and you wouldn't need the parameter at all). As long as you have your functions in a separate package as you posted here, though, you will need to pass them arguments explicitly. And I'm not sure you want to get into using impure functions, anyway.

Comment: Again, sorry for the lack of question and by the way, thanks for the clear answer. If I wanted to use function 1 with Random_Number as argument, I'd have to write it down like this right?           IF rand = ("001" or "010") THEN
  Modified_Number <= function1(Random_Number);

Answer (score 1):

Another difficulty with this code :

```
    IF rand = ("001" or "010") THEN
```

is equivalent to

```
    IF rand = "011" THEN
```

and so on. This means that function3 can never be called because the second and third branches are both:

```
    ELSIF rand = "111" THEN
```

This may not be the behaviour you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was planning to use a syntax like: Modified_Number <= function1(Random_Number) when rand = "001" or "010" but I didn't know if it would be correct.

Comment: Same problem. The `=` is not distributed across the `or`, and `or` is a logical operation, so `= "001" or "010"`, in whatever type of conditional statement you use it, will always be equivalent to `= "011"`.

Comment: However ... `IF rand = "001" or rand = "010" THEN` or the equivalent `when` would work... except for evaluating "rand" twice. You need to evaluate "rand" once, store it (in a variable) then use THAT in the IF statement.

Comment: So basically, I could store it in a variable and then use the variable in the if. Could it also work by replacing `or` by `xor` like this? `IF rand = "001" xor "010" THEN`